# AngularJS, $routeProvider and resolve: Hello World example not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to put together a Hello World example of `$routeProvider` using `resolve` to feed data into the controller. [This is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8363ZkIJP1ii7aIrfrM7?p=preview); the error I get is `Unknown provider: greetingService` however the factory is declared before the controllers and the config. What's wrong with this code?

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

   <a href='#option1'>click me to show Hello World</a>

   <br/><br/>

   {{message}}

   <br/><br/>

   *****

   <div ng-view></div> 

   *****


</body>
```

template.html:

```
<div ng-controller="templateCtrl">
   {{hello}}
</div
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);


angular.module('app')
.factory("greetingService", function($q, $timeout){
   return {
       getGreeting: function(){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $timeout(function(){
               deferred.resolve("Hello");
           },1000);
           return deferred.promise;
       }
   };
});


angular.module('app')
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

     $scope.message = "Message in the main controller";
});

angular.module('app')
.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope,greeting) {

    $scope.hello = greeting + " World";

});

angular.module('app')
.config(function($routeProvider,greetingService) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/option1', {

        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'templateCtrl',
        resolve: {
            greeting: function(greetingService){
                return greetingService.getGreeting();
            }
        }

      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are injecting `greetingService` in your main `app.config`. Remove that line and it will work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GRqZQrEvKa6dntx39qOu?p=preview

You can only inject providers into config blocks (i.e. $locationProvider, $routeProvider), not instances. You can inject your instances into the `.run` block of an app.

Comment: thanks, but if you click the link it shows {{hello}} instead of Hello World

Comment: fixed this, I also had to remove the controller from the template. This is the plunk that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/8363ZkIJP1ii7aIrfrM7?p=preview